How error `Flow Version Limit Exceeded, Details: You can only have 50 versions per flow.` can be avoided?
Looks like every time when a deployment happens on the environment using CI/CD process, a new Flow version is created, which leads to an error
Flow Version Limit Exceeded, Details: You can only have 50 versions per flow.

How this error can be fixed or avoided?
If we try to delete the flow,
sf project delete source -r -m Flow:VeryPopularFlowWithTooManyFlowVersions
we receive another error
Component Failures [1]
=================================================================================
| Type  Name                     Problem                                          
| ───── ──────────────────────── ──────────────────────────────────────────────── 
| Error VeryPopularFlowWithTooManyFlowVersions insufficient access rights on cross-reference id 


We can create a script deleteFlow.sh to try to delete all versions it finds, starting from v1 and ending v50
for i in {1..50}; do 
    sf project delete source -r -m Flow:$1-$i 
done

and then just execute
./deleteFlow.sh VeryPopularFlowWithTooManyFlowVersions

Is this doing something to avoid deleting the currently active version? Can you explain how it does?

trying to delete all versions it finds, starting from v1 and ending v50... I guess this wouldn't be able to delete the currently active version but for my case I don't care since CI/CD will deploy the new active version of the flow....

Please [edit] the answer to make that clear.

@PhilW ok, updated

That edit does not warn people that this might delete all versions, or explain that an active version cannot be deleted (if that is the case). Please be absolutely clear as to what the end result is in explaining the behaviour of your script.
